# Elasticsearch recent accessed document

Tags: elasticsearch

In my application I have the requirement for recently accessed documents to appear first in the search.

Let's say I open a file on my application that is indexed on Elasticsearch as well so if I now make a search this file should appear first in the search results since it was recently accessed.

How can I achieve this? I know that I need to update something on the document itself but what? Is there already a field for this use case or I need to create a new one? And if so I can I make Elasticsearch give more weight to this one?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add a date in your mappings:

```
"lastasseceddate": {
        "type": "date" 
      }
```

Of course, you would have to update it each time a document is accessed. Obviously if you have many update / user connected at the same time you could have some trouble. Dont forget to check if your "refresh" settings is ok, you could consider to force refresh after any update too.

To retrieve documents, just sort by this date field (desc).

```
"sort": [
    {
      "lastasseceddate": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
```

If your users modify documents each time they accessed it, you could consider use collape (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/collapse-search-results.html)

Note:
If you need only keep the X last accessed documents (let s say the last 5), the best solution is to keep es document in a static list on application side.